# How to find out what a hash means?

Tags: caching, logging, hash

We are having lots of strange requests in our log to a resource called "09fe503e5898bcba55056542d470a803", such as:

```
GET /cache/09fe503e5898bcba55056542d470a803
GET /something/cache/09fe503e5898bcba55056542d470a803
GET /something-else/cache/09fe503e5898bcba55056542d470a803
```

We have no resource or cache entry called like that so don't understand where these calls come from.

The funny thing is that a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2209fe503e5898bcba55056542d470a803%22) on this hash returns many results as if this hash was somehow special (if I change just one character, no Google result comes up).

Does anybody know what this mean? Is there any way to find out where this hash comes from?

Comment: Might be some vulnerability scanner, looking for a hole irrelevant for your system. Not really programming question, though...

Comment: And hash itself might be just MD5 from some well-known word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource requested isn't necessarily a hash - it **could** just be a fixed size random sequence of bytes **encoded in hexadecimal**.

If it was a hash, and you had **identified** the algorithm used to compute it (MD5 etc.), you could search some **rainbow tables** (databases of keys that map to hashes), to try and identify the key (although I doubt this would be of any benefit).

> The funny thing is that a Google search on this hash returns many results as if this hash was somehow special (if I change just one character, no Google result comes up).

Interesting observation, this suggests that the string is common, but doesn't allude to it's source. Converting the [string to text](http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) doesn't show anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is a random blob of letters or characters. Looks like it is MD5, so I wouldn't be too worried about it. Also, what does your website do, and does it communicate with your server?

Answer (score 0):

> The funny thing is that a Google search on this hash returns many results as if this hash was somehow special (if I change just one character, no Google result comes up).

IMO, the hash isn't special, that's just the same application generate it as in your case...